# How do I copy a Google search URL in iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, google, mobile-safari

I’m writing a Stack Exchange answer from my iPhone, and I want to include a Google search URL. How can I copy the URL of the search results from iOS Safari? Going up to the address bar and tapping “Copy” only grabs the search terms, not the full URL. I’m using iOS 13.4.1.

Note: My question is very similar to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/59475/62960), except that question is asking about the desktop version of Safari, not iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Tap the sharing sheet at the bottom (the icon in the middle)
- Select "Copy"